# $[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$ or $[a,a^{\dagger}]=I$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, notation, commutator

$[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$ or $[a,a^{\dagger}]=I$?
On every book i read $[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$. But doesn't $a$ have infinite dimension? So why does the commutator go to a number which is one dimensional?

Answer (score 10):

When people write $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ it is the exact same thing as $[a,a^\dagger]=I$. Sometimes people use $1$ to denote the identity operator as well, it is just a notation.

If you are not convinced of that notation you can also think it as being the operator $M_1$ which multiplies one ket by unit. This operator is the identity operator itself, since we have that

$$M_1(|\varphi\rangle)=1 \cdot |\varphi\rangle=|\varphi\rangle.$$

And obviously it is quite common to denote the operator $M_\lambda$ which multiplies a ket by $\lambda$ by just $\lambda$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might like the strongly-typed programming languages like Haskell.

The symbol $1$ has a polymorphic type, meaning that its type is context-dependent. For example in the standard construction of the counting numbers $\mathbb N$, which is some subset of the type `forall x. Set<x>`, the symbol $0$ actually stands for the (also polymorphic!) empty set $\emptyset = \{\}$, the symbol $1$ actually stands for the set $\{0\},$ the symbol $2$ actually stands for the set $\{0,1\}$ which sounds like a type error when you expand it to $\{0, \{0\}\}$ until you realize that the two literal $0$ expressions have different types.

Similarly when you then construct the integers $\mathbb Z$ from the counting numbers, you have $1$ as having the value $1 = \{(n_1, n_2) : n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb N, n_1 + 1 = n_2\}$. (The idea is that each pair represents $n_1 - n_2$ but subtraction is not well-defined over all $\mathbb N$, so we define each number in $\mathbb Z$ as an equivalence class of points in $\mathbb N^2$ over the equivalence relation that $(n_1, n_2) \equiv (m_1, m_2)$ when $n_1 + m_2 = m_1 + n_2.$)

Similarly when you then construct the rationals $\mathbb Q$ from the integers, you have $1$ as having the value $1 = \{(z_1, z_2) : z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb Z, z_2 \ne 0, z_1 = z_2.\}.$ (Again, $(z_1, z_2)$ represents $z_1/z_2,$ but since we can't necessarily perform that with integers, so we define each number in $\mathbb Q$ as the equivalence class of points $\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z - \{0\})$ such that $(a_1, a_2) \equiv (b_1, b_2)$ when $a_1 \times b_2 = b_1\times a_2.$)

Then we construct the reals from the rationals, and this definition is even more abstract: a real number is a "space between rationals," so the real number $x$ is defined as the set of rationals contained in the real interval $(-\infty, x)$. In other words, a real number is a proper subset $A \subset \mathbb Q$ which is closed from below (i.e. if both $b \lt a$ and $a \in A$, then $b \in A$) and contains no maximal element (i.e. if $a \in A$ there exists $a' \in A$ such that $a' > a$) and the real number $1$ is $$1 = \{q : q \in \mathbb Q, q < 1\}.$$
Notice again that the right-hand $1$ has the type of rational numbers, and the left-hand $1$ has the type of real numbers.

Finally, we can consider the space of $n\times n$ square matrices (we will leave alone the question of whether these are matrices of rational, real, or complex coefficients for a second). Here there exists an identity matrix and scalar multiplication, so it makes sense to define $1 = I_n, 2 = 2 I_n,$ and so forth, using our scalar multiplication to define these numbers as diagonal square matrices. This is not counterintuitive because the diagonal matrices commute with all other matrices, just like scalar multiplication does. So there is no problem with this, either.

Comment: As much as I am a fan of Haskell, I don't think the analogy works very well here. The most relevant mathematical structure here is the [operator algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_algebra), with a unit operator defined rather naturally via its action on the Hilbert space. Granted the number 1 is used as a notation of all the examples you gave here, the reason why it is adopted is different in each case.

Comment: 1 is adopted in $\mathbb Z$ constructed by the Peano axioms because adding 1 is equivalent to the successor function as we would expect. 1 is adopted in $\mathbb Q$ constructed from equivalence classes of ratios because it captures the idea of ratios of two equal numbers in basic arithmetic as we would expect. Neither of these two senses relate to the operator $I$ very well. We don't think of the "successor" $a+ I$ of some operator $a$ as very useful, neither do we really have a natural way of defining ratios of operators.

Comment: 1 is adopted as a notation for the unit operator only because the operator algebra (being unital and has character 0) has $\mathbb Z$ as a subring, and the action of elements of $\mathbb Z$ on the Hilbert space is well defined and natural, so the correspondence of $I$ to 1 is natural. Thus the other answer is more straightforward and on point in my opinion.